# Can a school network administrator see app search history?

Tags: networking, history

Quick question,

If your college network is monitored by a network admistrator, I know they can see safari browsing history and traffic, but let's say you are using the tumblr or facebook app on an iphone 5s, would the administrators be able to see your history or traffic?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be able to see it?  You are connecting to the same equipment.

Comment: See your local history? probably not. They could record their own version of it however. In general they won't have access to local resources on your device, but can certianly monitor the data you send through their network.

Comment: Unless every comment and answer here is: "Absolutely not, it's not possible" (Which isn't the case, it 100% is possible) Then I'd recommend you use a VPN on your iPhone if you really want to be safe of university spying.. (My point is, if you really care then you won't risk it)

Comment: They can't see your history(browser) but for sure they can know your conections historial.

Answer (score 3):

The network administrator can of course see what addresses you connect to. You should know though, that Facebook, and Tumblr apps on Iphone, both use HTTPS.

This means that the network administrator can see that you are connecting to Tumblr/Facebook servers, but have no idea of the content of the pages you are looking at.

A way for the administrator to find out the content of your browsing would be to act as a man in the middle between Facebook and you, but with the Iphone app, or most browsers, this is not possible without your browser/mobile alerting about an untrusted certificate.

In other words, the administrator might notice you are **using** Tumblr/Facebook, but can't see what you are browsing.

Comment: It's worth noting that some organizations request/require that you install a certificate before using their network, usually for security purposes and curtailing SSL malware.  If that's the case, then you won't even get a browser warning if they act as a man in the middle.

Comment: this is correct.

Comment: @GuitarPicker Oh yes, I've heard of such practice too. Although in this case it would be unlikely if a private mobile device is being used.

Answer (score 1):

They are likely to see outgoing traffic to `*.facebook.com` (or other) from your device.

If you use the same device to connect to local web portal, they can associate your mac adress ("physical network layer") to you dynamic adress, and to traffic with facebook and tumblr.

Note however, this is not automatic, and unless you've done bad thing your local admin are not going to search/browse your navigation "for fun" on a daily basis.